# get all of the inputs in a containing table with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to make a 'select all' style checkbox in jQuery. here is current markup:

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th><input class='select-all' type='checkbox' /></th>
        //etc..
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class='list-select' type='checkbox' /><td>
     //etc..
    </tr>
    //more <tr>s..
  </tbody>
</table>
```

what's the easiest way to get all of the 'list-select' checkboxes from the click event of the select all checkbox?

```
$(".select-all").click(function() {

});
```

There could be more than one of these on the page, so it has to be relative. i.e. I can't just use `$(".list-select")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ru3Nv/

At the core is:

```
$('.select-all').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('table').find('.list-select').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Note that I'd also recommend adding listeners on the .list_select boxes so that if any of them become unchecked, the select all becomes unchecked, and if all of them are checked individually then the select all becomes checked as well.

Comment: nice. I was not aware of the `parents()` function. I had tried `parent()` to do something similar but it will not work that way. Also, good idea on the additional listeners for list-select checks

Answer (score 1):

If the select all check box is always in the `<thead>` of the table, then you can use:

```
$(this).parents('table').find('.list-select').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: `parents` will find **all** `table` elements that are ancestors, rather than stopping on the first one. `closest` is a better choice.

Comment: You're right, although I don't think the SO is having nested tables, `closest` more precise, it is more efficient and always returns a single element.

Answer (score 0):

*(Sorry, misread question at first.)*

Probably go up to the closest `table`, then down to the `.list-select`:

```
var select = $(this).closest('table').find('.list-select');
```

(`this` will be the `.select-all` that was clicked, because this is inside the event handler.)

[`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) starts with the element you give it and moves up through the hierarchy to find a match, and stops with the first one it finds. Then [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) is sort of the opposite, it goes from there to find descendant elements matching the selector.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to achieve this:

```
$(".select-all").change(function(){
  if($(this).attr("checked")=="checked"){
    $(".list-select").attr("checked","checked");
  }
  else{
    $(".list-select").removeAttr("checked");
  }
});
```

That gives your .select-all checkbox the functionality to select and de-select all .list-select checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. This is Logic for Checking checkboxes and all Checkbox. Use the pattern for class for single checkbox => "chkSelect-'AnySignificantName'" and for all checkbox => "chkSelect-'AnySignificantName'-all" to make use of this logic.

For example, use classs "cheSelect-Grid-All" for checkbox "cbSelectAll1" of header and "cheSelect-Grid" for the table body rows.

```
$("body").on("click", "input[type='checkbox'][class*='chkSelect-']", function () {
var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
var selfClassname = '', type = 'single', singleClassName = '', allClassName = '';
if (classes.length > 0) {
    classes.forEach(function (a) {
        if (a.indexOf('chkSelect-') > -1) {
            selfClassname = a;
            return;
        }
    });
}
if (selfClassname !== '') {
    if ((selfClassname.match(/-/g) || []).length === 2) {
        type = 'all';
        allClassName = selfClassname;
        singleClassName = allClassName.replace("-All", "");
    }
    else {
        singleClassName = selfClassname;
        allClassName = singleClassName + "-All";
    }
    if (singleClassName !== '' && allClassName !== '') {
        if (type === "all") {
            $("." + singleClassName).prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
        }
        else {
            if ($(this).is(":checked") && $("." + singleClassName).length === $("." + singleClassName + ":checked").length) {
                $("." + allClassName).prop("checked", true);
            }
            else {
                $("." + allClassName).prop("checked", false);
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```